# Using "sc" command to control services with whitespace in name

Tags: windows-service, windows-command-prompt, windows

I need to stop service on remote machine. The problem is that service name contains whitespaces, and I get a message, that such service does not exist.

```
sc \\machine stop "service name"
```

How can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go into the Services admin console and double-click the service, you should see that the service has a "Service name" that is shorter and has no white space, you can use this name instead of the full display name.

Example:

For this service below, that has spaces in its display name, you would use this command line:

```
sc \\machine stop adobearmservice
```

[image]

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if your service does actually happen to have a name with whitespace then you can use double quotes and it will correctly identify the service.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same situation, But My service "Service Name" and "Display name" both are having the whitespaces. Any possible solution ?